# What's a good way to do specific algebraic operations on an expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

This is the first time I've submitted a question so please forgive my inexperience.

I want to simplify the following expression `Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]]` which is equivalent to `1/Sqrt[1 + Xt^2/Rt^2]`

The steps I want to use are:

1. Square the expression to get rid of the radical.
2. Multiply the numerator and denominator by the quantity `Rt^2`.
3. Simplify the denominator.
4. Produce the final result by taking the square root.

My code is:

```
cat = Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]]
$Assumptions = {Rt \[Element] Reals, Rt > 0}
num = Numerator[cat] Rt^2
den = (Denominator[cat]^2) Rt^2 // Simplify
catnew = Sqrt[num/den] // Simplify

catnew === cat
```

I have three specific questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?  (I'm sure there is!)
2. How do I check to see if the original expression (`cat`) and the new one (`catnew`) are algebraically equivalent?
3. How can I submit a question that includes the exact symbolic output from Mathematica?

Thanks

Comment: With version 13.2.1, `Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]]` automatically simplifies to the target form. What version are you using?

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the OP meant by "is equivalent to" that it "evaluates to". The phrasing is ambiguous though. -- OP, did you mean `Numerator[cat]^2` or are leaving it off since you know the numerator? I use your basic approach frequently. On the specific example, `Simplify[Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]], {Xt, Rt} \[Element] Reals]` is another way. Also `Simplify@Sqrt@Together[Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]]^2]`. Not sure if you care where the square root is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Whenever working in an irrational field like inverse trigonometics or elliptic functions, try to rationalize in the power field. Here

```
   cat^2 /. {a_/b_ :> Sqrt[ a^2/b^2]} // Together // Sqrt//PowerExpand
```

$$\frac{\text{Rt}}{\sqrt{\text{Rt}^2+\text{Xt}^2}}$$

The results may by wrong with respect to signs or by steps in the complex argument by multiples in $\pi$, but yield a  standard algebraic form for small positive variables as a guideline to find a simple target form.

What brings us to Q2:

Fast but not quite True in the complex domain:

```
   Series[Cos[ArcTan[Xt/Rt]] == Rt/Sqrt[Rt^2 + Xt^2], 
          {Rt, 0, 18}] //PowerExpand

   True
```

There has much work to be done, to get the true algebraic expressions in the other quadrants

```
     ComplexPlot3D[
         Cos[ArcTan[(2 + 7 I)/Rt]] - Rt/Sqrt[  Rt^2 + (2 + 7 I)^2], 
            {Rt, -6.0 (1 + I), 6.0 (1 + I)}, 
             AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"},BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 7}]
```

[image: difference complex plot]

Q3:  Mathematica Input and Output: Copy Cell as Plain text or Input Text by a right click.

Simply indent the paste here by more than 4 characters. Use Shift+Return to break indented lines.

For nice TeX input, right click cell and copy as LaTeX, paste here in a separate line between \$\$  \$\$

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I'm just curious about the rule. I see that it replaces a fraction with the square root of the fraction squared.
    $$\text{PowerExpand}\left[\text{Together}\left[\sqrt{\text{cat}^2}\right]\right]$$
    $$\frac{\text{Rt}}{\sqrt{\text{Rt}^2+\text{Xt}^2}}$$
The command above appears to do the same thing.